# How to sum if within percentile in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

[image]

It contains more than 100k rows.

I know how to get the median (or other percentile) values per week:

```
SELECT DISTINCT week, 
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY visits) OVER (PARTITION BY week) AS visit_median
FROM table
ORDER BY week
```

But how do I return a column with the total visits within the top N percentile of the group per week?

Comment: Sample input and clear expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want `percentile_cont()`. You can try using `ntile()`.  For instance, the top decile:

```
SELECT week, SUM(visits)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY week ORDER BY visits DESC) as tile
      FROM table
     ) t
WHERE tile <= 10
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week;
```

You need to understand how `NTILE()` handles ties.  Rows with the same number of visits can go into different tiles.  That is, the sizes of the tiles differ by at most 1.  This may or may not be what you really want.

Comment: The OP is looking for the percentile rank and therefore needs PERCENT_RANK. NTILE(100) is a bad choice for a couple reasons: first, as you said, "Rows with the same number of visits can go into different tiles." That means that NTILE doesn't always produce the correct answers. 2nd - NTILE performs very badly.  Note this article which covers this topic (including why you should never use NTILE for calculating percentile rank): http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PERCENT_RANK/141532/